# FFMPEG: How do I set PMT PID on ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pid

I want to set PMT PID/PCR PID/Video PID/Audio PID.

I know how to set except PMT PID.

＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃

`ffmpeg -i TESTVIDEO.avi`  (Input File name)

`-mpegts_start_pid 0x0010`  (PCR PID)

`-streamid 0:0x00ff`      (Video PID)

`-streamid 1:0x0100`        (Audio PID)

`TESTOUT.ts`            (Output File name)

＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃＃

How do I set PMT PID on ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

> -mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0x1500 (PMT PID)

Also the following information should be helpful:

> ffmpeg -h muxer=mpegts